# Error al intentar ejecutar consulta Object of class mysqli_result could

Tags: php, json

Aquí esta mi código `php` que lo que hace es mostrar en `JSON` la información de la tabla.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
include('conexion.php');

$result  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM localidades").mysqli_error($con); //<<<<<<Aqui marca el fallo!
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $arr[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($arr);
    echo $json;
}
```

**ERROR**

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: Elimine ese punto. `PHP` usa el punto para concatenar en su código intenta concatenar un `mysqli_result` que es lo que retorna `mysqli_query` , con una cadena que retorna `mysqli_error` lo cuál es incorrecto. debería ser quizá un `or` en lugar del punto. `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM localidades") or mysqli_error($con);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es bastante claro , `PHP` usa el punto **.** para concatenar dos o más valores, en su código intenta concatenar un `mysqli_result` que es lo que retorna `mysqli_query` , con una cadena que es lo que retorna `mysqli_error` lo cuál es incorrecto.

Debería ser quizá simplemente un `if` , para validar esto

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM localidades")) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $arr[] = $row;
    }
    $json = json_encode($arr);
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: ahora me sale el siguiente error _Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object_ en la linea del while.

Comment: @ManuelMorales verificó que el nombre de su tabla  del select  sea correcta?

Comment: si, es correcto, a que se debe el error?

Comment: @ManuelMorales el error mayormente es cuando la consulta que intenta ejecutar retorna falso debido a que está mal construida entre otras razones. entonces la principal acción debería ser verificar esto.

Comment: esta correcto, intente colocar el nombre de otra tabla y funcionar perfecto, pero en _localidades_ no funcionar ¿?

Comment: Sí con otra tabla funciona. debería funcionar con todas. no sabría decirle porque no funciona con localidades.